# Why do I get syntax error when using selenium in jenkins?

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

In a jenkins environment I want to use selenium, but what I get is an error (when trying to import the webdriver):

```
+ python -c 'from selenium import webdriver'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/jenkins/04/workspace/platform.alex-test/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "/jenkins/04/workspace/platform.alex-test/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 34, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "/jenkins/04/workspace/platform.alex-test/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 991
    return {k: size[k] for k in ('width', 'height')}
```

Any idea what could go on?

- Version python: 2.6.6
- Version selenum: 3.7.0

Here is the complete code I execute in jenkins:

```
virtualenv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install selenium
which python
python -c "import selenium; print selenium.__version__"
pip freeze
python -c "from selenium import webdriver"
```

According to the documentation selenium 3.7.0 is compatible with python 2.6...

Comment: Can you give some idea about the code block you are executing?

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver`. Its in the backtrace: line 1....

Comment: [dictionary comprehension appeared in v2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the documentation given [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) is incorrect. Seleniu 3.7.0 is indeed incompatible with python 2.6: [Here is the issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5018)!